# Traversing a string in xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a string of 15 bytes. For example, it is an ip address. (123.45.67.890) I need to add leading zeroes like this (123.045.067.890) and then remove the decimals (123045067890). The final out should have only 12 bytes after adding zeroes and removing decimals. I need to do this in xslt/xml. Please put your thoughts.

Comment: Which specific XSLT processor will you be using?

Comment: I am using XSLT 1.0

Comment: But which XSLT 1.0 processor? If you don't know, see here how to find out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25244370/how-can-i-check-which-xslt-processor-is-being-used-in-solr/25245033#25245033

Answer (score 1):

If your processor supports XSLT 2.0, you could do:

```
<xsl:value-of select="for $i in tokenize($ip, '\.') return format-number(number($i), '000')" separator=""/>
```

Comment: Thanks Michael. What does the variable ' i ' specify in this code?